# Top of Android keyboard color line, how to disable or make transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem when I start to scroll to the EditText wiggets that are under keyboard. The problem is with not showing EditText in full, as you can see in the picture.

[image]

And all EditText wiggets below this E-mail have the same problem. This blue line hides one part of them.

I have put all in the "ScrollView > LinearLayout" but nothing helped.

I tried with `android:focusable="true"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, also nothing.

Any suggestions where to start search?

Comment: Let's see, in what control did you apply the focusable property?

Comment: I added it in EditText wiget in xml layout, nowhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Probel was with ScrollView, I had set padding to it, so when keyboard is called the padding remains in the bottom.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
```

I just set that padding to LinerLayout that is inside ScrollView and remove padding from ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Mmmm the keyboard layout is implemented in the keyboard application. Different keyboard apps will show different layouts. There is no API available to remove this line.

The Android API only allows you to hide the virtual keyboard:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```